# __init__ is not called

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

in the below code I am learning the difference between **new** and **init**.
when I run the code I receive the following error:

**error**:

```
cls: <class '__main__.ThreadsWithSync'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "m:\python lessons\ThreadsWithSync.py", line 37, in <module>
    ThreadsWithSync()
File "m:\python lessons\ThreadsWithSync.py", line 12, in __new__
    cls.onCreateObject()
File "m:\python lessons\ThreadsWithSync.py", line 20, in onCreateObject
    print(instance)
File "C:\Users\Amr.Bakri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 842, in __repr__
assert self._initialized, "Thread.__init__() was not called"
AssertionError: Thread.__init__() was not called
```

**code**:

```
import threading
import logging
import time

class ThreadsWithSync(threading.Thread):

def __new__(cls):
    """
    For object creation
    """
    print("cls: %s"%(cls))
    cls.onCreateObject()
    
@classmethod
def onCreateObject(cls):
    """
    This will be invoked once the creation procedure of the object begins.
    """
    instance = super(ThreadsWithSync, cls).__new__(cls)
    print(instance)
    return instance

def __init__(self):
    """
    For object initialization
    """
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    print("self: %s"%(self))
    self.onInitializeObject()

def onInitializeObject(self):
    """
    This will be invoked once the initialization procedure of the object begins.
    """
    print("self: %s"%(self))
    
ThreadsWithSync()
```

Comment: Why is `__new__` throwing away the new object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__repr__` in `threding.Thread` checks whether the object has been initialized or not. This is being called when you are doing `print(instance)` inside `onCreateObject`. That check is required by the `__repr__` implementation to function correctly (without throwing an `AttributeError`).

If you overwrite the `__repr__` from `threading.Thread` then your example will work

```
class ThreadWithSync(threading.Thread):
    ...
    def __repr__(self):
        return "hey"
```

This results in the output:

```
cls: <class '__main__.ThreadsWithSync'>
hey
```

Edited to add full example:

```
import threading


class ThreadsWithSync(threading.Thread):
    def __new__(cls):
        """
        For object creation
        """
        print("cls: %s" % (cls))
        cls.onCreateObject()

    @classmethod
    def onCreateObject(cls):
        """
        This will be invoked once the creation procedure of the object begins.
        """
        instance = super(ThreadsWithSync, cls).__new__(cls)
        print(instance)
        return instance

    def __init__(self):
        """
        For object initialization
        """
        super(ThreadsWithSync, self).__init__(self)
        print("self: %s" % (self))
        self.onInitializeObject()

    def onInitializeObject(self):
        """
        This will be invoked once the initialization procedure of the object begins.
        """
        print("self: %s" % (self))

    def __repr__(self):
        return id(self)


ThreadsWithSync()
```

Comment: I had an extra doubt: wouldn't OP need to do a super class init? i.e. `super().__init__(...)` ?

Comment: "I'm not sure why that check is required but it's there." - well, if you tried to `repr` an object *before* initializing it, the `__repr__` implementation wouldn't find the attributes it expects to be there. The assertion failure is just a little clearer than an AttributeError.

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj the canonical way would be to do `super(ThreadsWithSync, self).__init__(self)` but that's equivalent to `threading.Thread.__init__(self)` in this case

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica That does make sense. Edited.

Comment: would you please modify the code .. i am tryin to display a string from __repr__ but could not

Comment: apprciate it but ii want to display an informative trxt about the instance  i dont want to display "hey"

Comment: That requires more info about what you want to display. I can't tell you what to put there without knowing what to put there.

Comment: i mean, is there any built in method that provide such info....e.g;self,__str__ or self.__new___??!!

Comment: You can return the `id(self)` instead which will print the unique object identifier (in CPython at least). Edited to add in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What is written in this error message that you are trying to print object using print(instance) that is using build in **repr** method, but this object is not initialized yet as it is called before **init**.