# object method invokation is not possible

Tags: python, python-3.x

in the below code, i am trying to develop using the concept of multithreading and synchronization.
i developed the below code. however, at the run time, i receive the below error:

```
cls: <class '__main__.ThreadsWithSync'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "m:\python lessons\ThreadsWithSync.py", line 68, in <module>
    t1.spawnThread
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'spawnThread'
PS M:\python lessons>
```

please let me know why the method 'spawnThread' is not recognized

import threading
import logging
import time
from random import seed
from random import randint

```
class ThreadsWithSync():

def __new__(cls):
    """
    For object creation
    """
    print("cls: %s"%(cls))
    cls.onCreateObject()
    
def __init__(self):
    """
    For object initialization
    """
    #print("self: %s"%(self)) 
    self.onInitializeObject()

@classmethod
def onCreateObject(cls):
    """
    This will be invoked once the creation procedure of the object begins.
    """
    instance = super(ThreadsWithSync, cls).__new__(cls)
    #print("instace: %s"%(instance.__repr__)) #activate this line whenever an informative and descriprtive text about the instance is needed to be displayed
    return instance

def onInitializeObject(self):
    """
    This will be invoked once the initialization procedure of the object begins.
    """
    threading.Thread.__init__(self) #to initialize the super class
    print("self: %s"%(self))
    seed(1)

def __repr__(self):
    """
    similar to toString in Java
    """
    return "\n__class__: " + repr(self.__class__) +"\n__new__:" + repr(self.__new__) + "\n__str__: " + repr(self.__str__) + "\n__sizeof__: " + repr(self.__sizeof__)
    
def isNumPrime(self, targetNum):
    if targetNum == 0 or targetNum == 1:
        return False

    isPrim = True
    for i in range(targetNum):
        if targetNum % i == 0:
            isPrim = False
            break
    return isPrim

def spawnThread(self):
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()

def main():
    while True:
        thread_1 = threading.Thread(group = None, target = self.isNumPrime, name='Thread_1', args = (), kwargs=dict(targetNum=randint(0,100)), daemon = None)
        thread_2 = threading.Thread(group = None, target = self.isNumPrime, name='Thread_2', args = (), kwargs=dict(targetNum=randint(0,100)), daemon = None)


t1 = ThreadsWithSync()
t1.spawnThread
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to return the created object from `__new__`

Comment: i did ... please see onCreateObject method

Comment: There is no `return` in `__new__`. You are discarding the object returned by `onCreateObject`.

Comment: thanks for the precious info..i thought that as i am returning an object from a method that in turen is to be called from within __new__, i will get the same effect as if i am returning the created object from within __new__

Comment: Which they were already told but ignored: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66312641/print-statement-inside-init-is-never-executed and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66311963/init-is-not-called (see comment "why is new throwing away...?")